# images not appear when retrieve it from firebase to recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

can help me guys pls

I tried retrieve images from Firebase realtime database by URL i used Picasso library

**my problem that my images not appear when retrieve it from firebase to recyclerview**

I added code, database, and screen from app in below

dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.2'
```

the code

```
private RecyclerView rv_oil_list;
private FirebaseDatabase db;
private ArrayList <Oil_List_Model> list;
private OilListAdapter oilListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    rv_oil_list =findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    db =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    rv_oil_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv_oil_list.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));

    getList();
}

private void  getList()
{
    db.getReference("List_Of_Oil").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            list=new ArrayList <>();
            oilListAdapter = new OilListAdapter(new_list_of_oil.this,list, new_list_of_oil.this);
            rv_oil_list.setAdapter(oilListAdapter);
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot :snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Oil_List_Model menuModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(Oil_List_Model.class);
                list.add(menuModel);
                oilListAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);
                oilListAdapter.getItemCount();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(new_list_of_oil.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {

}
```

Adapter class

```
public class OilListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <OilListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List <Oil_List_Model> list;
private RecyclerView_InterFace recyclerView_interFace;

public OilListAdapter(Context context, List <Oil_List_Model> list, RecyclerView_InterFace recyclerView_interFace) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.recyclerView_interFace = recyclerView_interFace;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public OilListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new OilListAdapter.ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false));    }


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OilListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Oil_List_Model menuModel = list.get(position);

    holder.imageName.setText(menuModel.getOilName());

    Picasso.with(context).load(menuModel.getImageResource()).into(holder.image);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView imageName;
    CardView parentLayout;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
        parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                recyclerView_interFace.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Screen from my app
[app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mxv0.jpg)

Realtime database
[Firebase Realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYht6.jpg)

Comment: Try using Glide

Comment: can you share a link from your firebase

Comment: i used glide and not appear

Comment: I added database u can see it

Comment: oh thanks guys solved i don't know why my URL changed but i put URL again to database and worked'